# What is the LightGBM equivalent of .fit() to DecisionTreeRegressor/Classifier (from scikit-learn)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, lightgbm

I am trying to replicate the .fit() from lightgbm library in python, but there seems to be different methods for lightgbm Booster.

1. .update()
2. .refit()
3. .train()

I have tried all three to no avail.

```
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='friedman_mse', max_depth=3, 
                                          max_features=self.max_features, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                          min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                                          min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=5,
                                          min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0
                                          , random_state=0)

tree.fit(X, gradient)
```

works

This, however, doesn't work.

```
tree = lgb.Booster(model_file='lgbm_model.txt')

train_data = lgb.Dataset(X, label=gradient, free_raw_data=False)
valid_data = lgb.Dataset(Xtest, label=gradient_t, free_raw_Data=False)
```

## solution 1

```
tree.update(train_data) # gives me this error: 

AttributeError: 'Booster' object has no attribute 'train_set'
```

## solution 2

```
tree.refit(X, gradient, predict_disable_shape_check = True)
```

runs but doesn't seem to update the tree all that much

## solution 3

```
tree = lgb.train(self.params, 
                 train_data,  
                 valid_sets=valid_data,
                 num_boost_round= 10, 
                 keep_training_booster = True,
                 init_model = tree
                 )
```

doesn't run

Comment: Have you tried giving the booster as the parameter "init_model=Booster" to the lightgbm.train() of the Python API? This can be found in the documentation under https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html

Answer (score 1):

The LightGBM package for Python has different APIs. If you are using the [Training API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#training-api) then you should definitely use the `train` method:

> Perform the training with given parameters

However, if you want to stick to scikit-learn conventions then you should simply use the [scikit-learn API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#scikit-learn-api) with a [`LGBMClassifier`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm-lgbmclassifier) which offers a `fit` method:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb


clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
```